# Integrate $\sec(x^x)/(\tan{x})^{1/2}$ .

Tags: integration

I have to find the indefinite integral, is there any possible solution, as
I am not able to find one.

Please provide a solution if possible. Thank you!

Comment: What approaches have you tried?

Comment: I couldn't figure out an approach to start, tried some basic conversion but it didn't work.

Comment: i think this integral has no soluution in the elementary functions!

Comment: I doubt that this anti derivative can be expressed in terms of elementary functions. Is this a book problem?

Comment: @imranfat, maybe not, someone asked me

Comment: Well, I believe that this is not a book problem and I would suggest to move on to the next exercise :)

Comment: Wasn't it maybe $\frac{(\sec(x))^x}{(\tan(x))^{1/2}} = \frac{\sin^{1/2}(x)}{\cos^{x+1/2}(x)}$? But that's probably also not possible.